# In search for toy relations to test relational algebra

Tags: databases, relational-algebra

Does anybody know any toy database / relations that are particularly good and also **complete** to demonstrate and test relational algebra concepts?  I'm hoping some database researchers should have already made that and improved over long time from pedagogical practices.